Check if an any value implements an interface
Say I have a function printVar that tries to print out a variable. The only requirement is that the input variable implements the fmt.Stringer interface, but the underlying type of the variable can be anything, really.
I have a second function which determines whether or not to call printVar, receiving an any type. I can't type assert in the typical way because the variable is not of the concrete type fmt.Stringer, but of some other type that may or may not implement the String() method.
The problem is that if the concrete type of the variable is not fmt.Stringer, the type assertion will fail. How can I check if the variable implements the String() method?
import "fmt"

func printVar(printableVar fmt.Stringer) {
    fmt.Println(printableVar)
}

func maybePrint(item any) {
    printable, ok := item.(fmt.Stringer)
    if ok {
        printVar(printable)
    } else {
        // Do something else
        fmt.Println("Can't print", item)
    }
}

func main() {
    intArr := []int{20}
    someStr := "hi"
    maybePrint(intArr)
    maybePrint(someStr)
}

Clearly the item adheres to fmt.Stringer because fmt.Println() converts it just fine. And I understand that the ok is false because the item isn't the concrete type fmt.Stringer, it's some other concrete type that happens to implement that interface. But I don't know what the correct alternative is to do what I'm trying to do

"Clearly the item adheres to fmt.Stringer because fmt.Println() converts it just fine." -- This is incorrect. Just because something can be printed with fmt.Println it does not mean that that something implements fmt.Stringer. Using fmt.Println you can print int, bool, string, etc. values, none of which implement fmt.Stringer. Your root premise is false.

As @mkopriva commented, fmt.Println() does a lot of magic under the hood and can print values even if they don't have a String() string method (and thus they don't implement fmt.Stringer). The fmt.Stringer interface generally is for if you want to control / change what the default textual representation of a value should be.
So the values you try (of type []int and string) do not have a String() string method, but the fmt package does something to print them "intelligently" (human readable format).
But back to your original problem: fear not! You can not only type assert concrete types, you can type assert an interface type to!
Quoting from Spec: Type assertions:

[...] the primary expression
x.(T)

asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
[...]
If T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x implements the interface T.

So using
printable, ok := item.(fmt.Stringer)

is perfectly fine / OK here: if item implements fmt.Stringer, ok will be true, and printable will be a value of type fmt.Stringer.
See this example:
func printVar(printableVar fmt.Stringer) {
    fmt.Println("printVar called:", printableVar)
}

func maybePrint(item any) {
    printable, ok := item.(fmt.Stringer)
    if ok {
        printVar(printable)
    } else {
        // Do something else
        fmt.Println("Can't print", item)
    }
}

type foo struct{}

func (foo) String() string {
    return "you can print me"
}

func main() {
    maybePrint([]int{20})
    maybePrint("hi")
    maybePrint(foo{})
}

This will output (try it on the Go Playground):
Can't print [20]
Can't print hi
printVar called: you can print me

